# What is the method of AJAX-like linking two pages together?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I know that i've read about a new method of making CORS requests, using a technology similar to AJAX.

The way it works is pageA sends a request to pageB. An event is fired in pageB, with the URL of pageA. pageB can then decide whether it wants to allow or deny the connection. If it allows, an event is fired an pageA to that effect, and the pages are now connected. pageA and pageB can both send messages to each other, firing an event on the other.

Does anyone know what i am thinking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be describing [HTML5 Web Messaging](http://dev.w3.org/html5/postmsg/#dom-window-postmessage), which has nothing to do with either CORS or Ajax but lets documents on different origins communicate through frames and windows.

Comment: To amplify a little: pageA opens pageB as an iframe or another window; then pageA sends a message via Web Messaging (or some other mechanism) to pageB.  Javascript on pageB does whatever decision-making you want and then communicates with its server.  This technique *replaces* CORS and typically *uses* AJAX.

Comment: @Malvolio — There is no requirement that Page B communicates with its server (the only time I've used it has been to ask YouTube to adjust the size of a frame, and that was entirely handled client size) and this technique does not use Ajax. Ajax is all about making HTTP requests. This uses frames instead of HTTP requests.

Comment: I interpreted his question as about a way to avoid the cross-origin problem; I may have been reading to much into it.